# Programação MVC em PHP

Tags: php, mvc

Boa tarde, estou com uma dúvida em um exercício que fora me passado no curso.

Preciso fazer com que o *texto atualizado* seja um hyperlink que volte para o *hello word*, criando um loop entre eles, ou seja: *hello world* (hyperlink) > *texto atualizado* (hyperlink) > *hello world* (hyperlink). Porém não sei como vou fazer esse loop. Obrigado desde já!

**Model**

```
class Model
{
    public $text;

    public function __construct() 
    {
        $this->text = 'Hello world!';
    }       
}
```

**View**

```
class View
{
    private $model;
    private $controller;

    public function __construct(Controller $controller, Model $model)
    {
        $this->controller = $controller;
        $this->model = $model;
    }

    public function output() 
    {
        return '<a href="mvc.php?action=textclicked">' . $this->model->text . '</a>';
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
class Controller
{

    private $model;

    public function __construct(Model $model)
    {
        $this->model = $model;
    }

    public function textClicked()
    {
        $this->model->text = 'Texto Atualizado';
    }
}
```

**Instâncias**

```
$model = new Model();
$controller = new Controller($model);
$view = new View($controller, $model);

if (isset($_GET['action'])) $controller->{$_GET['action']}();

echo $view->output();
```

Comment: Programação inteira aqui:
http://collabedit.com/a49ft